# Stick title at top one below another similar to index of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I need to stick title of the content at the top one below other when the user scrolls. Right now I have used bootstrap `Scrollspy`. Which works well but I need to have below things in it. [Here is the codepen link.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzojvp). (Not added the code in SO editor as that shows mobile view in the editor.)

1. Currently, 2 titles appear on screen one inside Navbar and other from the Content.
2. A title should stick one below another as if its an index of the page.
3. When the user clicks on any titles page should scroll to that content (This is achieved in `Scrollspy`, but currently only the title with `.active` class is shown).

I am aware that writing custom JS would take some time for me(This would be last option for me). I tried to google this but most of the plugins are similar to Scrollspy.

I am ok to have any plugin for this Or any simple changes in `Scrollspy` could also work.

[image: This is how it should look]

Comment: Added it. When user clicks on "section 2" page should scroll to section 2 and scroll  "Section 3" title down.

Comment: that sounds like some kind of accordion?

Comment: Yes you could say that. But In accordion content is hidden. Its visible when you click on the header. But in my case title should stick at top when content is scrolled down and title should move down with the content when its scrolled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this what you are looking for. Let me know if you need any other change.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var navHeight, activeLiCount, activeLiHeight;
  $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

  function onScroll(event) {
    var previousScrollTop = 0,
      scrollLock = false,
      scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop() + $(".nav").height();
    $(".nav a").each(function() {
      var currLink = $(this),
        refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
      if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos) {
        currLink.parent("li").addClass("active");
        if (scrollLock) {
          $(window).scrollTop(previousScrollTop);
        }
        previousScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      } else {
        currLink.parent("li").removeClass("active");
      }
    });
  }

  $("#header a").click(function() {
    var pageId = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent("li").addClass("active");
    activeLiCount = $(this).parent("li").index();
    activeLiHeight = $(".nav li.active").height();
    navHeight = activeLiCount * activeLiHeight;
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(pageId).offset().top - navHeight
    }, 500);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}

#header {
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

ul.nav>li {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
}

.nav>li>a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

.nav li.active,
.nav a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.nav li.active {
  display: block;
}

.section h3 {
  padding: 12px 0;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

p {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="header">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#page1">Page One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page2">Page Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page3">Page Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page4">Page Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page5">Page Five</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="page1" class="section">
  <h3>Page one</h3>
  <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula
    pharetra.
  </p>
  <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula
    pharetra.
  </p>
  <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula
    pharetra.
  </p>
  <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula
    pharetra.
  </p>
  <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula
    pharetra.
  </p>
</div>
<div id="page2" class="section">
  <h3>Page Two</h3>
  <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula
    pharetra.
  </p>
  <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula
    pharetra.
  </p>
</div>
<div id="page3" class="section">
  <h3>Page Three</h3>
  <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula
    pharetra.
  </p>
  <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula
    pharetra.
  </p>
  <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula
    pharetra.
  </p>
</div>
<div id="page4" class="section">
  <h3>Page Four</h3>
  <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula
    pharetra.
  </p>
  <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula
    pharetra.
  </p>
  <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula
    pharetra.
  </p>
</div>
<div id="page5" class="section">
  <h3>Page Five</h3>
  <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula
    pharetra.
  </p>
  <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula
    pharetra.
  </p>
  <p>Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula
    pharetra.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Need few changes like no need of min-height: 100vh. I checked it works fine even after removing it.